# How to reset room database

Tags: android, android-room

I have tried many ways to reset it.

`allowBackup`and`fullBackupOnly` had been set to false.

`.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()`

and delete database and cache files directly.

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to uninstall the app, this deletes the database file(s). So rerunning starts from a brand new database.

To use `.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` you have to have to invoke a Migration by increasing the version number but NOT have a Migration for the particular path. You could argue that this doesn't reset the database as the newly created database will have the higher version number.

Using `clearAllTables` doesn't entirely reset the database as it will not delete the system tables. Most notably, sqlite_sequence, which is a table that hold the vale of the latest rowid on a per table basis. That is if you have `autogenerate = true` in the @PrimaryKey annotation for an field/column that resolves to a column type affinity of INTEGER then AUTOINCREMENT is coded then the sqlite_sequence table will be created (if not already in existence) and store the latest (and therefore highest) value of the said primary key. Thus if you have inserted 100 rows (for example) into a such a table, then after a clearAllTables the 100 will still be stored in the sqlite_sequnce table.

You could also, prior to building the database, delete the database. Here's an example that allows it to be deleted when building :-

```
@Database(entities = [Customer::class], version = 1)
abstract class CustomerDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun customerDao(): CustomerDao
    companion object {
        private var instance: CustomerDatabase?=null
        fun getDatabase(context: Context, resetDatabase: Boolean): CustomerDatabase {
            if (resetDatabase && instance == null) {
                (context.getDatabasePath("thedatabase.db")).delete()
            }
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,CustomerDatabase::class.java,"thedatabase.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as CustomerDatabase
        }
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): CustomerDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,CustomerDatabase::class.java,"thedatabase.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build()
            }
            return instance as CustomerDatabase
        }
    }
}
```

- note that in addition to requesting the reset, a check is also made to ensure that an instance of the database hasn't been retrieved.

This would also be more efficient as clearAllTables still incurs processing of the underlying data and the ensuing VACUUM which can be quite resource hungry.

Comment: I have tried to uninstall app and delete database files directly but didn't work. And you mean if I need to use .fallbackToDestructiveMigration() I still have to increase version?

Comment: Now I have tried this: context.getDatabasePath("test").delete(); at MainActivity when started And...Exception:Room cannot verify the data integrity.

Comment: @LovelyCat then your issue is more complex. You need to edit your question. To show the issues you get if you uninstall the App and rerun.

Comment: @LovelyCat Don't allow backups.

Comment: So what information should I provide. I have set allowBackup and fullBackupOnly to false

Comment: set allowBackup to false.

Comment: Although I uninstall the app and reinstall run. I really don't know how it got the old 
datas. It still throws: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.

Comment: That's because it's recovering the data from the backup. You could try coding .fallbackToDestructiveMigration and increasing the version number to a number greater than the database ensuring that there is no Migration to that version number. It should then attempt the migration, see that there is not a Migration and then delete the database and then create it and build the database according to the Entities. This assumes that you are not also using createFromAsset/File. You also wish to look at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup#IncludingFiles

Comment: So that's mean I could delete the backup directly?

Comment: And another error, If I add replace tag to `<application>` , will the allowBackup set to false? This is exception: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@allowBackup value=(false) from AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-36
 is also present at [ren.qinc.edit:lib:0.0.5] AndroidManifest.xml:12:9-35 value=(true).
 Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:allowBackup"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-128:19 to override.

Answer (score 1):

The Room database has a `clearAllTables` function that does clearing entities you defined with `@Entity` annotation. But there is a catch. It does not clear the system generated tables such as `sqlite_sequence`, which stores the autoincrement values.

But there are more factors to consider. Since `clearAllTables` itself run in a transaction, we cannot run combination of `clearAllTables` and clearing `sqlite_sequence` in a single transaction. If you try to run `clearAllTables` in a transaction, it will fail with an `IllgalStateException`.

The android SQLite database library creates an additional table called `android_metadata` which stores database locale, and the room database library creates another table called `room_master_table`, which keeps track of database integrity and helps database migrations. We should not delete or clear these two tables. Additionally, SQLite will create a `sqlite_sequence` table if you have defined autoincrement columns. Deleting this table is not allowed, but clearing this will reset the autoincrement values.

The room database compiler generates the `clearAllTables` function in the database class. Basically, it disables foreign key constraints, then starts a transaction and clears all rows in tables you have given in the database class, and after the end of the transaction, it re-enables foreign key constraints. See how this is done in the room database compiler source code [room / room-compiler / src / main / kotlin / androidx / room / writer / DatabaseWriter.kt / createClearAllTables](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-room-release/room/room-compiler/src/main/kotlin/androidx/room/writer/DatabaseWriter.kt#171). The generated function differs based on one factor, whether you have defined foreign key constraints or not.

Based on the compiler source code, I wrote an extension function to reset the database. It will clear all tables you defined and will reset the autoincrement values.

```
fun RoomDatabase.resetDatabase(tables: List<String>? = null): Boolean {
    val db = openHelper.writableDatabase
    val tableNames = db.getTableNames()
    val hasForeignKeys = db.hasForeignKeys(tables ?: tableNames.minus("sqlite_sequence"))
    val supportsDeferForeignKeys = db.supportsDeferForeignKeys()

    return try {
        if (hasForeignKeys && !supportsDeferForeignKeys) {
            // clear enforcement of foreign key constraints.
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = FALSE")
        }
        db.beginTransaction()
        if (hasForeignKeys && supportsDeferForeignKeys) {
            // enforce foreign key constraints after outermost transaction is committed.
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA defer_foreign_keys = TRUE")
        }

        // clear all tables including sqlite_sequence table.
        // deleting sqlite_sequence table is required to reset autoincrement value.
        val tablesToClear = tables?.let {
            if (tableNames.contains("sqlite_sequence")) {
                it.plus("sqlite_sequence")
            } else {
                it
            }
        } ?: tableNames
        for (tableName in tablesToClear) {
            db.execSQL("DELETE FROM $tableName")
        }

        db.setTransactionSuccessful()
        true
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        false
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction()
        if (hasForeignKeys && !supportsDeferForeignKeys) {
            // restore enforcement of foreign key constraints.
            db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = TRUE")
        }
        // blocks until there is no database writer and all are reading from the most recent database snapshot.
        db.query("PRAGMA wal_checkpoint(FULL)").close()
        if (!db.inTransaction()) {
            db.execSQL("VACUUM")
        }
    }

}

fun SupportSQLiteDatabase.getTableNames(
    exclude: List<String> = listOf("android_metadata", "room_master_table")
): List<String> {
    val cursor = query("SELECT DISTINCT tbl_name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'")
    val tables = mutableListOf<String>()
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        tables.add(cursor.getString(0))
    }
    cursor.close()
    tables.removeAll(exclude)
    return tables
}

fun SupportSQLiteDatabase.hasForeignKeys(tables: List<String>? = null): Boolean {
    val tableNames = tables ?: getTableNames(exclude = listOf("android_metadata", "room_master_table", "sqlite_sequence"))
    for (tableName in tableNames) {
        val cursor = query("PRAGMA foreign_key_list($tableName)")
        if (cursor.count > 0) {
            cursor.close()
            return true
        }
        cursor.close()
    }
    return false
}

fun SupportSQLiteDatabase.supportsDeferForeignKeys(): Boolean {
    // defer_foreign_keys is only supported on API 21+
    // Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP
    val cursor = query("PRAGMA defer_foreign_keys")
    return cursor.use { it.count > 0 }
}
```

Comment: I would also add assertNotMainThread() up there in case the main thread gets locked for a long period of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [clear all tables](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.html#clearAllTables())
THis deletes all rows from all the tables that are registered to this database as Database.entities().

Comment: I tried to user clear all tables but it still didn't work. Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.

Comment: It's you have changed the schema? Clear all tables doesn't change anything in the schema? 
Did you by any chance change something in your database entities?